# Using a default method for unmatched REST methods in Jersey

Tags: rest, jersey

I know this is not quite "restful" but, I want to learn if and how I can handle all requests which do not match any of the methods in my REST resource (I want to proxy these requests to another server). For example, it could be a method like:

```
@GET 
@Path("*") 
public Response defaultMethod(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response) 
{ 
    // do proxying here 
}
```

how can I achieve this?

BR,

SerkanC

Answer (score 9):

```
@Path("/{default: .*}")
```

This works for:

- `http://example.com/someUnexpectedPath`
- `http://example.com/someUnexpectedPath/withAdditionalSubPaths`
- `http://example.com/someUnexpectedPath/withAdditionalSubPaths?andParams=whatever`

Answer (score 2):

One possible option would be to define a custom 404 mapping. Since 404s handles all unmatched requests it should catch all undefined urls.

I added the following this to my `web.xml` file

```
 <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/404</location>
  </error-page>
```

Where location is the path you want to direct the request to. Then just define that the call as normal.