# Java REST is there a way to default to a particular method if none of the paths match? (Instead of getting a 405)

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, dropwizard

I apologize if some of my terminology is off, I'm still trying to learn:

I'm using the Dropwizard framework and I have a resource class with all my various POST/GET/etc methods. They all work fine when hit from Postman, browsers, etc. If I try something that has no matching path in the resource class I get an exception with HTTP status 405 - method not allowed.

Is there a way to default to some other method where I can display troubleshooting help -- like a list of what the available APIs are or a link to some documentation? Sort of like a try catch type of logic. Not sure what the options are or if there is a best way to do this.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is it JAX-RS (Jersey) or Dropwizard?

Comment: Dropwizard uses Jersey, so this should do:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104034/using-a-default-method-for-unmatched-rest-methods-in-jersey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you might want to do that. REST over HTTP is driven "mostly" by the HTTP method and the end-point the same will act upon it.

In any stack, try to avoid that since you have specific actions for specific resources...anything else should be treated as something the server didn't understand, in the same way the HTTP protocol would behave.

Being said that, just apply a wildcard, usually `*` to one of the methods as a fallback action. That should work on Jersey and Spring Boot (MVC) as well.

Comment: OK, thanks for explaining why NOT to do this. As well as offering a solution.